# Im unable to use my Epson receipt printer after updating my application to .net 4.6.2

Tags: .net, vb.net

The application is built using VB.NET. It used to work well when compiled as .NET Framework 4.0 target, but after upgrading it to .NET Framework 4.6.2, i needed to upgrade Microsoft POS for .NET from version 1.12 to 1.14.1 for compatibility.

Now whenever i try to print a receipt i get an error in Event Viewer like:

"TypeLoadException while loading C:\Program Files\EPSON\OPOS for .NET\trace\Epson.opos.tm.trace.dll. Error: Method 'get_CapRecRuledLine' in type 'jp.co.epson.upos.trace.T81.pntr.T88VTraceService' from assembly 'Epson.opos.tm.trace, Version=1.11.4092.19294, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation."

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling that Epson stuff after upgrading ?

Comment: @aybe yes, i have upgraded the Epson drivers and other software to latest version but same results.

Comment: You might want to downgrade then, I had a similar issue that got solved that way (check the README as well maybe there's some info). The thing is you're jumping many versions at once from 4.0 to 4.6.2.

Comment: @Aybe Eveything is working fine, i needed to upgrade to version  .NET 4.6.2 but its only the Epson printer that prints through Microsoft POS for .NET that is not working, and i upgraded that too.